# VM file transfer to local machine

Tags: macos, scp, vmware-fusion

I have a VM running on my machine. I want to copy a file over to my machine that is currently running the VM. I was wondering how I can get this file on my local machine.

Comment: Tell us which VM software do you use, VM and host OS.

Comment: VMware fusion and OSX

Comment: what is the guest OS?

Comment: Can't you just drop and drag?

Comment: @JanDoggen nope strictly terminal

Answer (score 0):

`scp user@ip:/path/to/file_to_transfer filename`

From local machine input that command. Where `filename` is something you want to name the file